# I can not create a table in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to create the following table on the apex website but it gives me an error .I tested this in SQL plus and it worked perfectly.

```
    CREATE TABLE job_grade
   (Grade_level varchar(2) not null,
    lowest_sal number not null,
    highest_sal number not null);


INSERT ALL
    INTO job_grade
    VALUES ('A', 0, 1000)
    INTO job_grade
    VALUES ('B', 1001, 2000)
    INTO job_grade
    VALUES ('C', 2001, 3000)
    INTO job_grade
    VALUES ('D', 3001, 4000)
    INTO job_grade
    VALUES ('E', 4001, 5000)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

output:

```
   ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1829


4.     highest_sal number not null);
5. INSERT ALL
6.     INTO job_grade
7.     VALUES ('A', 0, 1000)
8.     INTO job_grade
```

Comment: you missing a semicolon?

Comment: @OldProgrammer where?

Comment: You tried to execute a SQL statement that included a special character.This error may occur if you've pasted your SQL into your editor from another program

Comment: @Ayse Can you name that character?

Comment: Or you should semicolon after insert query finish

Comment: for create -> In oracle, you can use semicolon or not when u ran query directly on DB. But when u using java to ran an oracle query, u have to remove semicolon at the end. and  write just create table query and you can try to use the run script command (F9) instead of run statement (F5).

Comment: The error indicates the *presence* of an illegal character, not the absence of one. If this is running as a command and not a script, then try again without the semi-colons and submit each statement separately.

Comment: @Ayse It still does not work and F9 is unknown in my editor

Comment: @pmdba this is running as a script and a semicolon is required

Comment: can you check that - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E92917_01/PDF/8.1.x.x/common/HTML/DM_Naming/2_Table_and_Column_Naming_Standards.htm

Comment: Your queries work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e91018c690fc6cba345cb00c94ebf911). Have you tried running the statements separately? (Possibly without the trailing `;`)

Comment: @MT0 It worked without I do anything. just restarting my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the SQL Workshop in apex. This does NOT work like sqlplus or sqldeveloper. If you click "run" apex will try and run everything as a single statement and this fails if there are multiple statements.

But don't worry, there is a simple workaround. Highlight the statement with the mouse and then click run. That will run only the highlighted statement. So in this case, highlight the `CREATE TABLE` statement and run it, then highlight the `INSERT ALL` statement and run it.

For running multiple statements, use "SQL Script" instead.

Comment: It worked without I do anything. just restarting my computer.But I have already done these things and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Do as @Koen said.

Alternatively, run a single CTAS which "combines" `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`:

```
SQL> create table job_grade (grade_level, lowest_sal, highest_sal) as
  2    select 'A',    0, 1000 from dual union all
  3    select 'B', 1001, 2000 from dual union all
  4    select 'C', 2001, 3000 from dual union all
  5    select 'D', 3001, 4000 from dual union all
  6    select 'E', 4001, 5000 from dual;

Table created.

SQL>
```