# why can't I run multiple statements in oracle?

Tags: oracle-apex

My problem in the following code is why I can not execute several commands together and I have to execute each one separately?

```
create table stores(id number,city varchar(30));
insert into stores values(1,'san fransisco');
insert into stores values(2,'chicago');
```

output:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1829
```

Comment: In what context are you trying to execute these commands? SQL Workshop? Within an app page or object? Multiple commands must generally be run either as a script, or within an anonymous PL/SQL block (e.g. `BEGIN ...(insert commands here)... END;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410033/i-can-not-create-a-table-in-oracle-apex/71412835) already explains how SQL Workshop works. That is designed to run a single statement. Why ? Because it is designed to work that way. My guess is that eventually they'll migrate to something more like sqldeveloper web, but for now, it is what it is.
You can run multiple statements if you define them as scripts (SQL Workshop > SQL Scripts).

Update: note that you can easily modify multiple dml statements into a single anonymous pl/sql block.

Example for a test table:

```
create table t (c VARCHAR2(100));
```

The statements below cannot be run together in SQL Workshop. It is necessary to highlight them one by one and run them:

```
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('c');
```

But the next statement can be run. Since it is a single anonymous pl/sql block it is just a single statement.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('c');
END;
/
```